# Nodejs aes decode from ios app data

Tags: ios, node.js, encryption

The guys who did the iOs app, use this method of encrypting data:

```
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted );

if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
{
  //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
  return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
}

free( buffer ); //free the buffer
return nil;
 }
```

which apparently it was taken from a code sample somewhere around internet. While digging around I've found that that piece of code is not safe, but since we have some data saved around our db we cannot change it. The problem is I must now decode that data from my nodejs server, which fails with error code:

```
  var ret = this._handle.final();
                     ^
  Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
  at Error (native)
  at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:202:26)
```

My current code for decrypting is:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
  , key = new Buffer('keyhere')
  , decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes128', key);
var decoded = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
decoded += decipher.final('utf8');
```

EDIT:
example data test

```
//---obj c
NSString *key = @"testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest";
NSString *plainText = @"test text";

NSString *encr = [plainText AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
//gives 5SCMEm11AJz0zV5UFhA9ag==

//nodejs
var crypto = require('crypto')
  , key = new Buffer('testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest')
  , cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', key)
  , plaintext = 'test text';
var encryptedPassword = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'base64');
encryptedPassword += cipher.final('base64')
//gives 8a2aVfXJjyivuigCz1EhIA==
```

Comment: 1. On nodejs you are specifying `base64` but there is no Base65 in the iOS code in the question. 2. Does nodejs default to PKSE#7 padding? 3. Does nodejs default to CBC mode, CCCrypt AES does. 4. Check the key is padded with zeros.

Comment: @Zaph the method above gets called with a base64 encoded string 2)the nodejs crypto library uses pkse 7 padding 3) I don't know, i'll try with cbc 4) the key is 32 bytes, so no padding needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the incomplete nodejs documentation you are specifying a 256-bit key on iOS (`kCCKeySizeAES256`) and a 128-bit key on nodejs (`aes-128-cbc`). Best guess is you need to specify `aes-256-cbc` for nodjs.

CCCrypt CBC mode with a NUL iv used an all zero iv. Check that nodejs has the same default. It is always best to fully specify all parameters and not rely on default values.

Things are a lot more clear and easier to test without using Categories, just passing the input value.

Comment: I know the objc code is not the best, but unfortunately I have no control over it. 
I've tried both aes 128 and aes 256 with null IV or none. I'm starting to think  I won't even be able to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to implement ( the broken ) algorithm was using forge js node module and pass it a null padded IV.

```
var key = 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest';
var iv = '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0';
var cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-CBC', key);
cipher.start({iv: iv});
cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(plaintext));
cipher.finish();
var cipherText = forge.util.encode64(cipher.output.getBytes());
```

Comment: The "solution"seems to be to use an implementation that sets the AES key size parameter based on the provided kay explicitly supply a null iv: 256-bit (32-byte) key. Note that the AES iv is the same as the block size: 16-bytes not 32-bytes as here. This is essentially the answer provided: use the same size AES key and insure the iv is 0s.